# Pandas Single Column Subsetting on Data Frame Produces Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

This is really a tale of two data frames, and strangely differing behavior.

I have two csv files which I am reading into pandas.  Each file is without header; the header files are stored separately.  Like this:

```
$ ls
A.csv A.header B.csv B.header
```

I'm using pandas to read these in, but first I need to parse the header:

```
def make_header(flnm):
    return open(flnm, 'rb').read().strip(' \t\n\r').split(',')

A_header = make_header('A.header')
B_header = make_header('B.header')
```

Now I can read in the csvs:

```
A = read_csv('A.csv', header=0, names=A_header)
B = read_csv('B.csv', header=0, names=B_header)
```

Let's make sure that this worked properly:

```
print type(A)
print type(B)
```

Which results in:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

as expected.

Now comes the strangeness which I can't sort out.  I want to select a single column from each of these data frames.  When I do this, one of the data frames returns a Series object (as I would expect) and one returns a one column DataFrame:

```
print type(A.A_x)
print type(B.B_x)
```

results in:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

As far as I can tell, I've treated these files identically from beginning to end, but have gotten different results.  What could be causing this?  Where is the flaw in either my treatment of the data, or my understanding of pandas?

**A Couple Things I looked Into**

The two columns have identical data types:

```
print A.A_x.dtype
print B.B_x.B_x.dtype
```

gives:

```
int64
int64
```

(of course I have to column select from the B data frame twice because of the strange behavior I am observing).

I also checked for repeated names in my header:

```
$ cat A.header | sed 's/,/\n/g' | grep A_x
> A_x
```

and

```
$ cat B.header | sed 's/,/\n/g' | grep B_x
> B_x
```

So each name in question appears exactly one time.

Comment: Does the first df only have a single column?

Comment: What version Pandas are you running, for me `0.14.1` returns a series whether or not the dataframe has only 1 column

Comment: No, they each have hundreds.

    A.shape, B.Shape
    (437583, 887), (470303, 683)

Comment: 0.12.0, from anaconda.

Comment: Could be a bug, can you upgrade and try again

Comment: This normally means you have duplicate column names. Are you certain this is not the case?

Comment: I'm certain that the column I am subsetting is not duplicated.

Comment: Updating to 14.1 fixed the issue.  This must have been a known bug I suppose.  Thank you Ed and joris for your help.